# Dynamic BigBinaryString implmentation in C++

Tags: c++, binary

I am writing a BigBinaryString class in C++ which abstractly holds the large binary string and can perform operations like xor, and, left shift and right shift.

I have stored the binary string internally as a vector of unsigned longs, so each element in vector consumes 64-bits from the bitstring.

I have decided to use have four types of constructors:

```
BigBinaryString(const string bitstring)   //for directly converting the bitstring to internal repr.
BigBinaryString()                         //initialize the binary string to 0.
BigBinaryString(const size_t num)         //hold the binary for corresponding unsigned long.
BigBinaryString(const vector<size_t> vec) //Directly pass the internal repr to the constructor for it to copy.
```

So far I have implemented **and**, **xor**, **equality** and **left shift** operators.
However, I feel the left shift operator has a very high time complexity in which the way I have implemented it.

So, I need a few suggestions on how to speed up the left shift operator so that I can implement the right shift efficiently as well.

The code so far is as follows:

```
#define SIZE_UNSIGNED_LONG (sizeof(size_t) * 8)


class BigBinaryString {
   private:
    vector<size_t> num;
    void reduce() {
        while (*num.rbegin() == 0) {
            num.pop_back();
        }
        if (num.size() == 0) {
            num.push_back(0);
        }
    }

   public:

    BigBinaryString() { num.push_back(0); }

    BigBinaryString(const size_t n) { num.push_back(n); }

    BigBinaryString(const vector<size_t> vec) {
        const size_t length = vec.size();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            num.push_back(vec.at(i));
        }
        reduce();
    }

    BigBinaryString operator&(const BigBinaryString& op) {
        vector<size_t> vec;
        size_t maxlen = max(num.size(), op.num.size());
        size_t minlen = min(num.size(), op.num.size());
        const size_t zero = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < minlen; i++) {
            vec.push_back(num.at(i) & op.num.at(i));
        }
        return BigBinaryString(vec);
    }

    BigBinaryString(const string bitstring) {
        string temp = bitstring;
        size_t dec = 0;
        while (temp.length() != 0) {
            if (temp.length() > SIZE_UNSIGNED_LONG) {
                dec = stoul(temp.substr(temp.length() - SIZE_UNSIGNED_LONG,
                                        SIZE_UNSIGNED_LONG),
                            nullptr, 2);
                temp = temp.substr(0, temp.length() - SIZE_UNSIGNED_LONG);
            } else {
                dec = stoul(temp, nullptr, 2);
                temp = "";
            }
            num.push_back(dec);
        }
        reduce();
    }

    BigBinaryString operator^(const BigBinaryString& op) {
        vector<size_t> vec;
        size_t maxlen = max(num.size(), op.num.size());
        size_t minlen = min(num.size(), op.num.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < maxlen; i++) {
            if (i < minlen) {
                vec.push_back(num.at(i) ^ op.num.at(i));
            } else if (maxlen == num.size()) {
                vec.push_back(num.at(i));
            } else if (maxlen == op.num.size()) {
                vec.push_back(op.num.at(i));
            }
        }
        return BigBinaryString(vec);
    }

    bool operator==(const BigBinaryString& op) {
        if (num.size() != op.num.size()) {
            return false;
        }
        size_t length = num.size();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (num.at(i) != op.num.at(i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool operator==(const size_t n) {
        BigBinaryString op(n);
        if (num.size() != op.num.size()) {
            return false;
        }
        size_t length = num.size();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (num.at(i) != op.num.at(i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool operator!=(const BigBinaryString& op) { return not(*this == op); }

    bool operator!=(const size_t op) { return not(*this == op); }

    BigBinaryString operator<<(size_t shift) {
        string bitstring = this->to_string();
        bitstring.append(shift, '0');
        return BigBinaryString(bitstring);
    }

    string to_string() {
        string suffix = "";
        string retval = "";
        string prefix = "";
        size_t n = 0;

        for (auto i = num.rbegin(); i != num.rend(); i++) {
            n = *i;
            prefix.clear();
            suffix.clear();
            while (n != 0) {
                suffix = (n % 2 == 0 ? "0" : "1") + suffix;
                n /= 2;
            }
            if (i != num.rbegin()) {
                prefix.append(SIZE_UNSIGNED_LONG - suffix.size(), '0');
            }
            prefix = prefix + suffix;
            if (prefix.size() == SIZE_UNSIGNED_LONG) {
                retval += prefix;
            } else if (i == num.rbegin()) {
                retval += prefix;
            } else if (i != num.rbegin()) {
                throw invalid_argument("prefix+suffix error");
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }
};
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If this is not homework, note that you're reinventing the wheel, as [boost::dynamic_bitset](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) has this functionality.

Comment: Sort of creating it for myself, so that I can use it in competitive programming in the future.

Comment: And what is the problem of implementing `<<`? Shift each `unsigned long long` in a loop and take care of carry bits.

Comment: Draw the shift on paper.  It should just be a loop that adjusts each of the `size_t` items in the vector depending on the shift amount.